# Why is std::declval not constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11

As in question - why is code like this illegal in cpp?

```
static_assert(std::declval<std::array<int, 4>>().size() == 4);
```

Is it an overlook in standard or there is some deeper rationale why `std::declval` is not `constexpr`?

Comment: `std::declval` is a function that should never actually be called, it should only appear in unevaluated contexts.  Not sure it makes sense to make it `constexpr` if you cant call it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This line:

```
static_assert(std::declval<std::array<int, 4>>().size() == 4);
```

fails to compile, because you are using `declval` in an evaluated context. This is not allowed, and if you do that your program is ill-formed. `declval` can only be called in unevaluated contexts such as in a `decltype` or `sizeof`.

Making a function `constexpr` means that it can be called at either run-time, or compile-time. Since `declval` simply can't be called, there's no point making it `constexpr`. I suppose there wouldn't be any harm in making it `constexpr`, but either way, it doesn't matter.